# The method findElements(By) in the type WebDriver is not applicable for the arguments (List<WebElement>) getting this error message

Tags: selenium

```
public static List<WebElement> read_element_file(List<WebElement> element)
        {

        List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(element);
        int i =li.size();   
        Iterator itr = li.iterator();   
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Object el = itr.next();
            String str = ((WebElement) el).getText();   
        }
        System.out.println(li);
       return li;
        }
```

Comment: public static List<WebElement> read_element_file(List<WebElement> element)
    {
    List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(element);
    int i =li.size();
    
    Iterator itr = li.iterator();
    
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
     Object el = itr.next();
     String str = ((WebElement) el).getText();  
    }
    System.out.println(li);
   return li;

Comment: Can you add more context to understand your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make some changes :

1. Return type should be list of **String** ,cause you are extracting **text** from `web element`.
2. You can simply use for each loop to iterate through a list.
3. **driver.findElements()** returns a list of web elements and takes **By** as a locator. You are doing `driver.findElements(element);` and **element** is already a list of web elements, So you will get **compile time error** saying : **element can't be resolve to a variable**

**Code :**

```
public static List<String> read_element_file(List<WebElement> element) {
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
        for(WebElement el : element){
            li.add(el.getText());
         }
        return li;
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.